# How to match columns of tables using JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I am just trying to learn JPA. I have three entity class looks like this. Relations are mentioned in the Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name="EMP_ID")
    private Integer empId;
    @Column(name="EMP_NAME")
    private String empName;
    @Column(name="EMP_ADDR")
    private String address;
    @OnetoOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PROJ_ID")
    private Project project;
    @OnetoOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TASK_ID")
    private Task task;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="PROJECT")
public class Project {
    @Id
    @Column(name="PROJ_ID")
    private Integer projectId;
    @Column(name="PROJ_NAME")
    private String projectName;
    @Column(name="PROJ_STATUS")
    private String projectStatus;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="TASK")
public class Task {
    @Id
    @Column(name="TASK_ID")
    private Integer taskId;
    @Column(name="TASK_NAME")
    private String taskName;
    @Column(name="TASK_STATUS")
    private String taskStatus;

}
```

My expected query is `select * from Employee a , Task b where a.proj_id= ? and a.task_id=b.task_id`

In my employee repository class I have a method

```
findEmployeeByProjectProjectId(int projectId).
```

But I am getting some excess data and not sure how to handle condition `a.task_id=b.task_id` .

Not sure I am doing anything wrong. Please suggest a solution or in case if I am doing something wrong Please correct me.

Comment: just a quick question what is the expected output you want ? all the data of `EMPLOYEE` & `PROJECT` or only the `EMPLOYEE` who has the tasks

Comment: Only from the employee who has the tasks

Comment: It will be good if task name also shown in that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `@OneToOne` Mapping Between `Employee-Project`  and `Employee-Task`.

Default `Fetch` policy for `@OneToOne` is `EAGER`. So whenever you will `FETCH Employee` entity, The associated `Project` and `Task` entities (if not null) will be Fetched too in the same query. You dont need the where clasue e.task_id=b.task_id.

```
    /* Repository method */
    /*Function 1*/
    @Query("Select E FROM Employee E WHERE E.project.PROJ_ID = :projID")
    Employee findByProject( @Param("projID") Integer projID);
    /*Function 2*/
    Employee findByProject( Project project); // This method can be used by passing a managed object of project.

   /*Usage of repository call*/
   Employee e = employeeRepo.findByProject(projectId); // Function 1
   Task t = e.getTask(); // this will not cause a query because Task was EAGERLY loaded with Employee entity.
   Project p = e.getProject(); // this will not cause a query because Task was EAGERLY loaded with Employee entity.
```

**Note: The second function which takes Project object should not be used like:**

```
     Project p=new Project();
     p.setPROJ_ID(projID);
     employeeRepo.findByProject(p); // Function 2 This will throw Exception stating that p is transient which cannot be used for querying.
```

To use the second method we can load the project proxy and then use it.

```
    Project p = entityManager.getReference(Project.class, projId);
    employeeRepo.findByProject(p); // Now this is okk
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your repository method to findEmployeeByProject(Project project).Then add to ProjectRepo findById,and in service layer of Employee find project by id and use this Project as a parameter of your findEmployeeByProject(Project project).

Comment: I didn't try this but a question for you before trying. How I will achieve employee.task_id= task.task_id ?

Comment: FindByTask(Task task) in EmployeeRepo,and  as task -> FindById in TaskRepo and realize service layers

Comment: This is the expected query select a.emp_id, a.emp_name,  b.task_name from Employee a , Task b where a.proj_id= ? and a.task_id=b.task_id. won't get it in oneshort ? Instead of this better to go with native query rt?. Just asking expert opinion.

Comment: By JPA you are not able to do it  in oneshort with relationship entities.By my opinion it is better to use hibernate and its methods,or use native query.

Comment: JPA with Nativequery is working fine. So I understand this is the major drawback of JPA rt?. I am not sure about hibernate.